# Tensorflow 1.3.0 NameError: name 'LinearRegressor' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the "get started" instruction on the official Website.
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/

I have tried both virtualenv and pip native installment method. And tensorflow can be imported at this time.

But when the tf.estimator.LinearRegressor can not be used. Do I need to link some kind of path to make the APIs started to work?

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/binwang/Documents/Learning_Tensorflow/3_Getting_Started_With_Tensorflow.py", line 13, in <module>
    estimator = LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)
NameError: name 'LinearRegressor' is not defined
```

The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# NumPy is often used to load, manipulate and preprocess data.
import numpy as np

# Declare list of features. We only have one numeric feature. There are many
# other types of columns that are more complicated and useful.
feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[1])]

# An estimator is the front end to invoke training (fitting) and evaluation
# (inference). There are many predefined types like linear regression,
# linear classification, and many neural network classifiers and regressors.
# The following code provides an estimator that does linear regression.
estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)

# TensorFlow provides many helper methods to read and set up data sets.
# Here we use two data sets: one for training and one for evaluation
# We have to tell the function how many batches
# of data (num_epochs) we want and how big each batch should be.
x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)

# We can invoke 1000 training steps by invoking the  method and passing the
# training data set.
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)

# Here we evaluate how well our model did.
train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print("train metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The code that raised the error and the code you posted here do not match.

Comment: `estimator = LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)` or `estimator = tf.estimator.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=feature_columns)` which one is it?

Comment: I solved the problem. Since I somehow changed the name of the defined function(tf.estimator.LinearRegressor). It's a minor mistake. If you're going to follow the instructions, the file should be able to run.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are not using tensorflow v1.3 ?

In v1.2 LinearRegressor was in *tf.contrib.learn* 
 [api doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/LinearRegressor) since v1.3 is in [api doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor).

Use the following to print the version you installed.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Comment: I just installed the newest version. It's 1.3.0. Do you recommend version 1.2 or 1.3 or 0.12?

Comment: I recommend you to double check the version you are using, and to make sure the tutorial your are following is in sync with the version your are using. My guess is that you're not really using 1.3.0 ...

Comment: Thanks! I have checked it, it's not wrong! Maybe, I will consider to use version 1.2 in the future.

Comment: Okay then check your naming more carefully as ayhan already mentioned the error message and the code do not match.

Comment: Thanks!  I have solved the problem! You are so helpful!

Comment: It could be interesting to update (edit) your question with how you solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks! It turned out to be my minor mistake. I have updated that.